# git and python: Clone a repository using subprocess module in python

Tags: python, git

I have a simple html file which accepts the repository path as argument and passes it over to the python cgi script, which then clones the repository using  the below command..

```
pr = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/git clone ' + str(repoPath)],
   cwd=os.path.dirname('/clone/here/'),
   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
   stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
   shell=True)
(out, error) = pr.communicate()
print out
print error
```

wherein, repoPath is the variable whose value i read from a html form. When i execute the above script, i get the below error

fatal: could not create work tree dir 'repository'.: Permission denied

But when i create a python script and directly run the above command, it works fine. Am i missing something here?

Comment: It seems that the commands in the subprocess.popen function are getting called as 'apache' user, since the cgi files are deployed in apache. Any idea how to create files/folders as non-apache user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory already exists, and is owned by a different user (most likely your shell login if you tested manually).

What you're doing is really unsafe. Instead you should create a unique directory and clone in there. I found this example [tempdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php#61436) function. (Note: there's a risk of endless loop if you can't write to `$dir`)

That way you will avoid any name collisions.

Comment: hmmm.. makes sense, will try out the solution and will let u know.. :)(

Comment: tried creating a dir using mkdir inside the cgi script. Its throwing "permission denied error.". Can you pls explain why this error is popping up and how it works when i try running only the python script from command line?

Comment: Your web server process most likely doesn't have write permissions to the given directory in that case.

Comment: so how do i run commands as a different user from the cgi script?

Comment: You don't, fix the permissions instead, or use a different directory. A typical permission for a temp directory is 1777, `chmod 1777 dir`

Answer (score 1):

Should be doing something like:

```
subprocess.Popen(['git', 'clone', str(repoPath), '/clone/here'])
```

I don't really understand what is the deal with the cwd statement you have there, but you need to close into the right location, otherwise the cwd could be anything, like '/'.